# My java if statement doesn't seem to be working

Tags: java, android, zxing

I'm not sure why but when I use zxing in my android application to get a barcode the format returns as EAN_13 but my if staement decides it's not, then shows me EAN_13 in my toast notification. Any clues as to why it's broken?

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    IntentResult scanResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    if (scanResult != null) {
        if (resultCode == 0){
            //If the user cancels the scan
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"You cancelled the scan", 3).show();
        }
        else{
            String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
            String format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT").toString();
            if (format == "EAN_13"){
                //If the barcode scanned is of the correct type then pass the barcode into the search method to get the product details
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"You scanned " + contents, 3).show();
            }
            else{
                //If the barcode is not of the correct type then display a notification
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),contents+" "+format, 3).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, I added .toString() to see what would happen, still goes through my if statement wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Java, you can't (well, *shouldn't*) use the `==` operator to compare two Strings. You should use:

```
if (stringOne.equals(stringTwo)) { ... }
```

Or, in your case:

```
if ("EAN_13".equals(format)) { ... }
```

In Java, when working with objects, the double equals operator compares two objects by *reference equality*. If you have two Strings:

```
String one = "Cat";
String two = "Cat";
boolean refEquals = (one == two); // false (usually.)
boolean objEquals = one.equals(two); // true
```

I say it *usually* won't be true because depending on how the creation of Strings is implemented in the system, it could save memory by allowing both variables to point to the *same piece* of memory. But, it's very poor practice to expect this to work.

**Side Note:** When using the strategy above, you have to ensure that the first String isn't `null`, or you'll throw a `NullPointerException`. If you have the ability to include external libraries in your project, I would recommend the Apache Commons Lang library, which allows:

```
StringUtils.equals(stringOne, stringTwo);
```

Answer (score 3):

When you use `==` you're comparing the two references to see if they're the same object (ie. they point to the same address in memory), rather than comparing the values of the objects. Use `format.equals("EAN_13")` instead.

Comment: While correct, I'm always more comfortable calling the `equals()` method on the quoted String. (Instead of on the variable.) This ensures that you won't encounter a `NullPointerException` in the case that `format` is null.

Answer (score 2):

For String comparison you should have to use .equals() method, actually this is doing comparison of two objects, and this method belongs Object class in java.
e.g:

```
        String val = "abc";
        if(val.equals("abc")){
           System.out.println("stings are equal!");
        }
```

on other hand you can use .compareTo() function in Comparable interface, 
e.q:

```
String val = "abc";
 if(val.compareTo("abc")==0){
   System.out.println("stings are equal!");
 }
```

**this is same as the above e.g.

Answer (score 1):

In java you cannot compare String with `==` 
 so please replace these operator with `.compareTo("str")` or `.equals()` methods.